# How to prevent table cells from resizing upon adding text

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have the following table (larger in reality, but just for simplicity):

```
<div>
   <table id="gametable">
        <tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td> <td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td> <td>6</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
        #gameTable {
        table-layout:fixed;
        position:absolute;
        height:640px;
        width:640px;
        margin-left:31%;
        margin-top:8%;
        }

        div {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        }


        td {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;   
        padding:0px;
        }
```

In my Javascript, I add a number/string to a specific table cell's innerHTML.

```
        table.rows[x].cells[y].innerHTML = mines;
```

When I do this it causes all the cells to resize, while the cell to which I added the text is the largest. The table size stays the same.
I would like each cell's size to stay the exact same, even when adding text to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a fixed width for your td:

```
td {
 width: 100px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;   
 padding:0px;
    }
```

Comment: This is unreliable unless also setting `table-layout` to `fixed` as explained in my answer.